# SQL Server: how to write a DELETE statement with a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have a SELECT query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Apples.ID, COUNT(Pips.Apples_ID) 
FROM 
    Apples 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table_B tb ON Apples.ID = tb.Apples_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
LEFT JOIN 
    Pips p ON tb.Apples_ID = p.Apples_ID
WHERE 
    tc.X IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    Apples.ID
```

The tables are:

- `Apples` which has a unique entry (ID) for each Apple.
- `Pips` which can have dozens of pips belonging to 1 Apple
- `Table_B` and `Table_C` are mapping tables to refine the search

I need to group the results because I do not want an Apples result for each and every Pip that apples can have. The SELECT statement works and returns a list of unique Apple IDs

I now want to DELETE these Apples. I changed my statement to:

```
DELETE Apples 
FROM Apples 
LEFT JOIN Table_B tb ON Apples.ID = tb.Apples_ID
LEFT JOIN Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
LEFT JOIN Pips p ON tb.Apples_ID = p.Apples_ID
WHERE tc.X IS NULL
GROUP BY Apples.ID
```

but got a syntax error on the `GROUP BY`.

I tried:

```
DELETE x 
FROM
    (SELECT Apples.ID 
     FROM Apples
     LEFT JOIN Table_B tb ON Apples.ID = tb.Apples_ID
     LEFT JOIN Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
     LEFT JOIN Pips p ON tb.Apples_ID = p.Apples_ID
     WHERE tc.X IS NULL
     GROUP BY Apples.ID) x;
```

But I got an error:

> View or function not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

How can I delete these rows I have identified in the `SELECT`, without using a temporary table or script?

Comment: Your query is practically leading to Delete from apples. What is that you are really trying to do and provide sample data.

Comment: You could simply use "Truncate table apples" if the user has right to truncate. It would be faster (IOW all those group by, left join etc query is unnecessary, your query is aiming to delete all from apples).

Comment: I am sorry, looking at again, the only factor there is you are eliminating the ones that tc.X is null. Rest do not have a role in this query.

Comment: Using GROUP BY in your deletion attempt serves no purpose. You don't filter the aggregated rows in any way. Just remove the GROUP BY clause from your first attempt. This is the same logic as your previous question - you simply started with a select query that counts without any real purpose.

Comment: Side point: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is usually faster than `LEFT JOIN` `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve this:

```
DELETE FROM APPLES WHERE ID IN
(
SELECT Apples.ID FROM Apples
LEFT JOIN Table_B tb ON Apples.ID = tb.Apples_ID
LEFT JOIN Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
LEFT JOIN Pips p ON tb.Apples_ID = p.Apples_ID
WHERE tc.X IS NULL
GROUP BY Apples.ID
) x;
```

Comment: What is the need for subquery?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the sub-query approach can be adapted to work by using an `IN ( ... )` clause on a normal single-table delete. This is the simplest way of adapting any select statement to a delete:

```
DELETE FROM Apples
WHERE ID IN (
   -- Sub-query selecting a single column of ID values
)
```

The sub-query can then be as complex as you like, using `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, etc, as long as it only has one column in the `SELECT` list.

In your specific case, however, there is no need:

- You have no `HAVING` clause, so the `COUNT()` doesn't change the rows to delete
- The `LEFT JOIN` to the `Pips` table has no effect on the result other than the `COUNT()`
- Mentioning the same row twice in a `DELETE` has no effect, so eliminating duplicates is unnecessary

You can therefore simplify this particular case without using the sub-query:

```
DELETE Apples 
FROM Apples 
LEFT JOIN Table_B tb ON Apples.ID = tb.Apples_ID
LEFT JOIN Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
WHERE tc.X IS NULL
```

Comment: Hmm I see you ended up the same way.

Comment: OK I can see that you can't see it. I was saying the same thing. FYI, you wrote the same query in a different way.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Your answer includes the simplification of removing the Group By, but mine simplifies *further*, by also removing the sub-query (`IN ( SELECT .... )`). You hinted at removing that in your comments under other answers, but didn't do in your own answer. All four answers will have the desired _result_, but that doesn't make them _the same query_.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Apples WHERE ID in 
(
SELECT a.ID FROM Apples a
LEFT JOIN Table_B tb ON a.ID = tb.a
LEFT JOIN Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
LEFT JOIN Pips p ON tb.Apples_ID = p.a
WHERE tc.X IS NULL
GROUP BY a.ID
) as q
```

Comment: What is the need for subquery?

Comment: That you need it or you can not do what the question asks. Syntax limitations are a thing.

Comment: @TomTom, that is not what I meant. I was asking the role of the subquery. Apart from tc.X is null can you tell me the need for it?

Comment: Actually it is. You need a subquery as you can not do a delete group by in one run by syntax. It is not possible to delete from a grouped by result. "DELETE statement with a GROUP BY" - it is asked for.

Comment: @IMSoP, good point.

Comment: @TomTom, you don't understand. I am asking the use of pips and group by. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that has a role in the query is tc.X is null. It can be null if there is no match or there is a match but the field X is null:

```
delete from Apples
where AppleId in
(
SELECT Apples.ID FROM Apples 
  LEFT JOIN Table_b tb ON tApples.ID = tb.Apples_ID
  LEFT JOIN Table_C tc ON tb.xID = tc.xID
  WHERE tc.X IS NULL
);
```

Comment: I'm confused: you questioned the use of sub-queries in two other answers, and then posted your own answer, using a sub-query, and not explaining it.

Comment: @IMSoP, there is nothing to be confused. It is not just a subquwery, please check the subqueries before makinf a deduction. Do you see any pips or group by?

Comment: @IMSoP you have a problem in seeing the difference.